# Powershell Text Field Auto-Complete

Tags: textbox, powershell-3.0

I have a text box for which I want to use autocomplete, reading from a text file source. I'm following the general example on MSDN here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx

My code doesn't throw an error (haha), but it's not populating the text box when I start a string, either.

```
$LogList = Get-Content(Resolve-Path "file\logs.txt")
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($LogList)
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

Is there a good example for this I can see online? I found one for a combo box, but I don't think it applies in my case.

Thank you!

Comment: What is `$comp_or_filepath`?

Comment: The variable name for my text box.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I hope you're looking for nearly 7 years on?

I'm looking into `AutoCompleteCustomSource` for PowerShell and very little info can be got on it.

**You were trying to access a prop that didn't exist.**

```
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

**That should have been:**

```
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteMode = 'SuggestAppend'
```

### Here's the code with comments:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#Form setup
$Form                                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.StartPosition                      = 'CenterScreen'

#Set up the control comp_or_filepath
$comp_or_filepath                        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$comp_or_filepath.Width                  = 280
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteSource     = 'CustomSource'
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteMode       = 'SuggestAppend'
$cbArr                                   = @('Mixed', 'More stuff', 'ANOTHER THING cONTENT', 'Item ?', 'Mixed item')
$comp_or_filepath.Items.AddRange($cbArr)

# Setup the autocomplete source by reading the file contents and adding each line.
$autoCompleteUsrSrc = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection
Get-Content(Resolve-Path "file\logs.txt") | ForEach-Object {
    $autoCompleteUsrSrc.AddRange($_)
}
$comp_or_filepath.AutoCompleteCustomSource = $autoCompleteUsrSrc

# Add controls and start form.
$Form.Controls.Add($comp_or_filepath)
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```